# Django dynamically generated serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, metaclass, django-serializer

Is there a way how to dynamically generate a Django rest framework serializers?

Considering this:

```
    class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
        class Meta:
            model = models.Blog
            fields = get_all_model_fields(models.Blog)
    
    class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
        class Meta:
            model = models.Post
            fields = get_all_model_fields(models.Post)
     
    
    class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
        class Meta:
            model = models.User
            fields = get_all_model_fields(models.User)
```

I am wondering if something like following example could be possible:

```
from django.apps import apps

models = [model for model in apps.get_models()]

for model in models:
    type(model.__name__+'Serializer',(serializers.ModelSerializer,),{
       type("Meta",(),{
           "model":model,
           "fields": get_all_model_fields(model)
       })
    })
```

Or is there any other way how to generate DRF serializers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function to build a `ModelSerializer` for a given `Model` (tested with Django 3.2, DRF 3.12.4 and Python 3.8):

```py
import types
from functools import lru_cache
from typing import Type

from django.db import models
from rest_framework import serializers

@lru_cache(maxsize=0)
def model_serializer(model: Type[models.Model]) -> Type[serializers.ModelSerializer]:
    meta_class = types.new_class("Meta")
    setattr(meta_class, "model", model)
    setattr(meta_class, "fields", "__all__")
    result = types.new_class(
        model.__name__ + "Serializer", (serializers.ModelSerializer,), {}
    )
    setattr(result, "Meta", meta_class)
    return result
```

If you are certain that you will call this function only once for each serializer, you can omit the [@lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) to preserve some memory.

Example usage:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    some = models.CharField(max_length=123)
    other = models.IntegerField()

MyModelSerializer = model_serializer(MyModel)
my_serializer = MyModelSerializer({"some": "abc", "other": 1234})
my_serializer.is_valid(True)
```

To add the serializers for all your models to the current module's namespace:

```py
from django.apps import apps

for model in apps.get_models():
    serializer_type = model_serializer(model)
    globals()[serializer_type.__name__] = serializer_type
```

Comment: this looks great! I am just not seeing where the variables 'types' comes from

Comment: @AustinHallett My bad, I now added the missing `import types`.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach will work - but for Django to find about these serializers you have to assign them to the module namespace.

In your code, you just call `type` - the serializer class is created and "thrown away" immediately. Even if the base Django class `serializers.ModelSerializer` keep a reference to it in a registry, you would not be able to import your serializers and make use of them.

All you have to do is to add them to the dictionary returned by `globals()`. Likewise, the namespace you create for the class also has to be a dictionary  -since you are calling "type" but not actually assigning its name as "Meta", you create a set, not a dictionary, and your call to type will fail as it was expecting a dictionary.

So, I did not check if the code actually will work, but the idea, based on yours is:

```
from django.apps import apps

models = [model for model in apps.get_models()]

for model in models:
    name = f"{model.__name__}Serializer"
    globals()[name] =  type(name,(serializers.ModelSerializer,),{
       "Meta": type("Meta",(),{
           "model":model,
           "fields": get_all_model_fields(model)
       })
    })
del models, model, name
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it. What's the use of `del models, model, name` ? Why are you doing that?

Comment: it is not needed - it is just that as these variables are created at the module root as tools to create the classes that will be used, they have no use afterwars. With the `del` statement they won't be visible to one importing the module - and the namespace stays cleaner. But it is really cosmetic.