# How to store and retrieve unstructured SQL primitive key value pairs in Python?

Tags: python, sql, json, django

I have some unstructured key value pairs I eventually want to store in a PostgreSQL database using the Django framework. It is mostly a debugging dump, so I don't want to query it in SQL but retrieve the whole thing and then deal with it on the Python side.

For example:

```py
data = {
   "name": "bob", 
   "size": Decimal("173.4"), 
   "logged_in_at": datetime.now()
}
```

However, I can not just create a `Model` and a table for it because the data are unstructured and can have any field name. (I can ensure though that the name adheres to both Python and SQL syntax rules.)

Applying [entity-attribute-value model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) would be overkill because I don't want to query single fields of my data, just retrieve the whole thing.

I cannot use [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) or JSON in general because it cannot process `datetime` and `Decimal` reliably.

I'm could use a [BinaryField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield) to store [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) data but dread the security implications.

I could [dynamically create serializers for Django REST framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64810287/django-dynamically-generated-serializer/67250329#67250329) and the related models but dread the necessary abstract meta voodoo and how to deal with changes in the underlying data models during runtime.

I took a quick look at [MessagePack](https://msgpack.org/), it seems to have the same issues as JSON.

[Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf) at least have a `Timestamp` type but do not have a decimal type. Applying ye olde "represent decimals as integers" trick would lose type information and make integer indistinguishable from decimals.

Because this is only a single field, introducing an additional NoSQL database feels like overkill. Also, at least MongoDB doesn't seem to have a native decimal datatype.

Currently I'm leaning towards writing a JSON encoder and decoder that converts all the fields to `str` and prefix it with type information, for example:

```py
encoded_data = {
   "name": "string:bob", 
   "size": "decimal:173.4", 
   "logged_in_at": "datetime:2022-01-04T00:54:14.245607"  # ISO format
}
```

Then I could store this in a `JSONField` or even `CharField`.

However, this seems to be a lot of code, steps and CPU for such a seemingly simple task.

Are their any better solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [arbitrary typed data in django model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2637438/90527)

Comment: ... "[Django: storing/querying a dictionary-like data set?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24688388/90527)"

Comment: @outis Thanks, but not really. Entity attribute model would be overkill as I don't want to query singular fields in the data, just retrieve the whole thing. (It's mostly a structured debugging dump.)

Comment: The question seems to be asking for a serialization format & library, one that supports some partially specified (possibly extensible, possibly limited) set of types and is safe enough with untrusted data. Such recommendations are beyond the scope of SO.